# Rotating a VC presented as UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios8

iOS 8. I am presenting a view controller with presentation style: UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext. This works great until I rotate my device, at which time the presented view is not properly adjusted.

Example: I presented over a portrait context. Entire screen covered by my new view (which has semi-transparencies). I rotate to landscape. The presented view rotates, but is now centered and remains at portrait width.

Both the presenting VC and the presented view are created in a storyboard using autolayout. Since I can't add constraints to the topmost view in a VC (right?) I'm not sure how to keep my presented view entirely covering the view below it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can happen if Presentation in the Segue is set to Page Sheet. In the storyboard, change the presentation to Full Screen or Over Full Screen

Since you're not using a segue, use UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen.

Comment: Great tip. I wasn't using a segue, but you led me to try `UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen` which seems to work -- although now my status bar is disappearing in landscape mode. Investigating that...

Comment: Updated the answer to include your situation without a segue.

Comment: Thanks. My status bar issue was due to the parent not explicitly preferring it to be visible. All set now.